# How to display graph using d3.time.scale with day only

Tags: d3.js, time

I want to draw a graph to display the time.  i just want to see the day in the x axis not the time. However, after trying a lot of solutions, i still cannot eliminate 12PM between two consequence days.
Example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3306147

Comment: Can you share your work? A fiddle would be better.

Comment: Thanks Fawzan, i posted it in fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/k92tou4z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the solution:
scale.ticks(d3.time.day, 1)